# Installation of Java JDK 11 doesn't include rt.jar

Tags: java, android, java-11

I installed the JAVA JDK 11 on Windows 10 and expected it to install rt.jar somewhere.
The JDK is supposed to contain the JRE, which should have rt.jar, but there is no rt.jar
in the folder C:\Program Files\java\jdk-11.0.12 that was created.

I am asking about rt.jar since my Android Studio build is complaining:

```
class file for java.util.Objects not found
```

So I assume something is wrong with my JRE installation.  rt.jar is supposed to contain the file Objects.class.

java -version returns this:

```
java version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.12+8-LTS-237)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.12+8-LTS-237, mixed mode)
```

Comment: No Java installation from Java 9 onwards contains an rt.jar - this file has been removed with Java 9. What is your Android Studio version?

Comment: @ThomasKläger:  It is Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 1.   Build #AI.203.7717.56.2031.7621141, Built August 7, 2021.   It seems strange to me that the download site only has this "2020" version, but I made every update that it suggested on startup.